# After upgrading to 15.10: Login loop after purple screen, locked out from network on tty1

Tags: boot, networking, upgrade

I just upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 on a hphp envy 15 laptop. After installation completed, system rebooted and then kept rebooting the screen and getting finally stuck with the screen turned off. I managed to enter recovery mode and then started a session on tty1. Seems the network is broken too:

If configuration wlan0 up

Gives input/output error from siocsifflags. I really need the laptop to work, so please anyone help.

EDIT: Thanks for no help. I solved by installing 15.10 from live usb alongside my main partition and then moved files to new partition and deleted the old one. Took me a day to complete but at least now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you had the proprietary AMD driver installed. It was broken for a couple of weeks. Fixed now. A fresh install would have used the open-source radeon driver.